# Trouble understanding Cloud Function Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to cloud funcations node.js and type script. I am running the below code and getting the error below and can't make sense of it after watch a ton of videos about promises and searching other questions.

any help would be appreciated.

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

```
exports.compReqUpdated = functions.firestore
      .document('/compRequests/{id}')
      .onUpdate((change, contex)=>{
        const newData = change.after.data();
        //const oldData = change.before.data();
        const dbConst = admin.firestore();
        const reqStatus:string = newData.requestStatus;
        const compId:string = newData.compID;
        const reqActive:boolean = newData.requestActive;
    

    if (reqStatus == "CANCELED" && reqActive){

        const query = dbConst.collection('compRequests').where('compID', '==', compId);
        
        const batch = dbConst.batch();

        query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
          const docs = querySnapshot.docs;
          for (const doc of docs) {
            console.log(`Document found at path: ${doc.ref.path}`);
            console.log(doc.id);
            const docRef = dbConst.collection('compID').doc(doc.id);

            batch.update(docRef, {requestStatus: 'CANCELED',requestActive: false});

          };
          
          return batch.commit()
          })
        
        .catch(result => {console.log(result)});

    }else{
        return
    }
   
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firebase [**docs**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_.documentbuilder.html#on-update) state that the callback passed to the **`onUpdate`** function should return **`PromiseLike`** or **`any`** value, but you aren't returning anything right now. If you change your code to something as follows I reckon it should work as expected:

```
exports.compReqUpdated = functions.firestore
  .document('/compRequests/{id}')
  .onUpdate((change, contex) => {
    const newData = change.after.data();
    //const oldData = change.before.data();
    const dbConst = admin.firestore();
    const reqStatus: string = newData.requestStatus;
    const compId: string = newData.compID;
    const reqActive: boolean = newData.requestActive;


    if (reqStatus == "CANCELED" && reqActive) {

      const query = dbConst.collection('compRequests').where('compID', '==', compId);

      const batch = dbConst.batch();

      return query.get().then(querySnapshot => {
        const docs = querySnapshot.docs;
        for (const doc of docs) {
          console.log(`Document found at path: ${doc.ref.path}`);
          console.log(doc.id);
          const docRef = dbConst.collection('compID').doc(doc.id);

          batch.update(docRef, { requestStatus: 'CANCELED', requestActive: false });

        };

        return batch.commit()
      }).catch(result => { console.log(result) });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. After looking at your code it all finnally makes sense. 8 hours sleep might have helped too!